# Rewrite rules for angular and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I'm following this article (the bottom section about using the URL Rewrite). My IIS Express (launched from VS) config file seems to be located C:\Users[usernamehere]\documents\IISexpress\applicationhost.config.

I place the rewrite rule inside the `<system.webServer>` tag like that article (and a lot of other articles I've read) say to. So it looks like:

```
<system.webServer>

        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angularjs routes"
                    stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                        matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" 
                        matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" 
                        pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>

... all the other crap that was already there
</system.webServer>
```

In my VS project I have index.htm off the root and my test views under a Views folder. This is the index.htm and it works when I click the link just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <p><a href="/">Main</a></p>

    <a href="red">Red</a>
    <a href="green">Green</a>
    <a href="blue">Blue</a>

    <!-- below is where the partial pages will replace -->
    <div ng-view></div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/red", {
            templateUrl: "Views/red.htm",
            controller: "redController"
        })
        .when("/green", {
            templateUrl: "Views/green.htm",
            controller: "greenController"
        })
        .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl: "Views/blue.htm",
            controller: "blueController"
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    app.controller("redController", function($scope){
        //alert("Red");
    });

    app.controller("blueController", function ($scope) {
        //alert("Blue");
    });

    app.controller("greenController", function ($scope) {
        //alert("Green");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem comes when I try to type in one of those pages direction: ie. http://localhost:60553/red

I get a 404. Which tells me that rewrite rule isn't being hit and doing it's job. Why am I getting a 404 even with that rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing this is because your `Views` folder has a `web.config` that explicitly blocks request to it.  That is placed there by default in MVC projects for security reasons.

Note the following code in `Views/Web.Config`

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

If you comment this out, your code should work.

However, I would advise moving your angular views to a different folder that isn't sort of a de-facto reserved folder for MVC.  Change to something like `ngView` and this code will work.  It will be cleaner and clearer that way, and you don't run the risk of exposing your razor code to snooping users.

**UPDATE**
The above is not the issue, per comments.  The issue is that the rewrite rules were not being used from the file mentioned.  Move them to web.config if possible - that will avoid setting up global rules that will apply to all iis express apps anyway.

Comment: Don't see that. I created a blank web project so no MVC stuff was setup. This is what my handlers section looks like in web.config.

<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>

Comment: Also, I am able to type in the address bar mysite.com/Views/red.htm and it returns the page. Obviously it doesn't run any angular so you see all the brackets and such but it allows me to go there so no permission issues.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a rewrite issue, then.  You wouldn't get to the url if browsing manually if the rewrite was the issue.

Comment: You are getting the 404 in javascript, right?  Or is it directly in the browser?

Comment: I get it if I type the url direction in the browser. If I use the links in index.htm it works fine. This leads me to believe it's a rewrite issue.

Comment: OK, I see now.  Have you tried placing your rewrite rules in your web.config?  Are you sure IIS express is using your designated .config file?

Comment: I have not tried that. Everything I've read says do it on IIS Express config. I do not know how to tell if IIS Express is using this config. All of this stuff is sort of black boxish.

Comment: Putting it in projects web.config under system.webServer worked! Damn these sites telling me to put it in IIS Express's config. Thank you!